# Mysql-query-with-groupby-is-extremely-slow

Tags: mysql

I have a database using the following schema:

```
       CREATE TABLE `sls_report` (
      `report_id` bigint(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `report_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `cust_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `client_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `customer` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
     `user_id` int(9) DEFAULT NULL,
      `salesman` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `agent_code` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
      `index_id` int(9) DEFAULT NULL,
      `index_code` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
      `index_label` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
      `family_id` int(9) DEFAULT NULL,
      `family_code` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
      `family_label` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
      `niche_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
      `niche_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `niche_label` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
      `segment_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
      `segment_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `segment_label` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
      `master_id` int(9) DEFAULT NULL,
      `master_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `master_label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `client_category_code` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
      `client_category_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
      `channel_id` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
      `channel` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
      `gross_amount` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
      `net_amount` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
      `promotion_amount` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
      `quantity` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
      `bu_unit_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
      `report_year` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (year(`report_date`)) STORED,
      `report_month` tinyint(4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (month(`report_date`)) STORED,
      `report_month_name` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (monthname(`report_date`)) STORED,
       PRIMARY KEY (`report_id`,`bu_unit_id`),
       KEY `sales_report_mv_reprtdte_usrid_slsman_idxcde_idxlbl_cstomr`                 
      (`report_date`,`user_id`,`salesman`,`index_code`,`index_label`,`customer`),
      KEY `srmv_buid_usrid_rptdate_chnl` (`bu_unit_id`,`user_id`,`report_date`,`channel`),
      KEY `sr_mv_custid_clntnum_customer_rptdte_grssamnt` 
      (`cust_id`,`client_number`,`customer`,`report_date`,`gross_amount`),
      KEY `sr_mv_buid_usrid_rptdte_custid_netamt_clntnum_cstmr` 
      (`bu_unit_id`,`user_id`,`report_date`,`cust_id`,`net_amount`,`client_number`,`customer`),
      KEY `sr_mv_buid_usrid_rptdate_idxcde_netamt` 
      (`bu_unit_id`,`user_id`,`report_date`,`index_code`,`net_amount`),
      KEY `sr_mv_buid_usrid_rptdate_idxcde_clntcatcde_netamt` 
      (`bu_unit_id`,`user_id`,`report_date`,`index_code`,`client_category_code`,`net_amount`),
      KEY `sr_mv_buid_usrid_rptdate_idxcode_qty` 
     (`bu_unit_id`,`user_id`,`report_date`,`index_code`,`quantity`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
     /*!50500 PARTITION BY LIST  COLUMNS(bu_unit_id)
    (PARTITION sr_mv_p1 VALUES IN (1) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION sr_mv_p2 VALUES IN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION sr_mv_p3 VALUES IN (3) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION sr_mv_p4 VALUES IN (4) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION sr_mv_p5 VALUES IN (5) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION sr_mv_p6 VALUES IN (6) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION sr_mv_p7 VALUES IN (7) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION sr_mv_p8 VALUES IN (8) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION sr_mv_p9 VALUES IN (9) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION sr_mv_p10 VALUES IN (10) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

I have a database using the following schema:

The table is very large and having partitions, it contains 4.5 million rows and growing further. I am running a query on it, trying to extract a report.

A query like this

```
  SELECT sales_report_id, report_year, report_month, report_month_name,
         cust_id, client_number, customer, user_id, salesman, index_id,  
         index_code, index_label,family_id, family_code,family_label,
         niche_id,niche_code, niche_label,segment_id,segment_code, 
         segment_label, master_id,master_code, master_label, 
         client_category_code, client_category_name, channel_id, 
         channel, sum(gross_amount), sum(net_amount),sum(promotion_amount),
         sum(quantity), bu_unit_id, 'INDEXID' 
from sls_report 
GROUP BY index_id, report_year, report_month, segment_id, niche_id,
         family_id, user_id, bu_unit_id,channel_id
```

It is taking more than 30 minutes.  Query does not have any where clause and is having only GROUP BY clauses.

I tried adding a composite index on the "index_id,report_year,report_month,segment_id,niche_id,family_id, user_id".

But the index is not getting used.

Please advise.

Regards
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm no expert on partitions, but I'm pretty sure yours are no help to you.

Comment: "My query s slow" complaints without a query plan, are mostly unanswerable

Comment: Also there are many more columns in your select than there are in your GROUP BY. This is a red flag.

Comment: What is the meaning of "index_id"?

Comment: It may be useful to build and maintain a "summary table" so that you don't have to rescan the entire table every time.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Answer (score 1):

As your query does not have any `WHERE`-clause, the database needs to go through every row in your database. With 4.5 million rows and so many columns, you are bound to hit the disk.

Also, your `GROUP BY` is incorrect as it does not include all non-aggregate columns shown in `SELECT`.